# Use function in Sql column header

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, columnheader

I wanted to know if it's possible to use a calculated function as a column header. Please see my code below. I would like to use yesterday's date for the sum case column header.

```
DECLARE @A AS VARCHAR(12)
SET @A = GETDATE()-1

select Data,  
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(DAY, Dt, GETDATE()) = 1and Type = 'Stock'
    then Spend end) AS  @A
from dbo.vw_ZZ_AS_ComplianceLeagueTable
group by Data
```

Comment: Any particular SQL query will always produce a result set with a fixed "shape" - the *names* and data types of the columns. You could write dynamic SQL to construct new queries at runtime - usually it's easier to keep the fixed shape and leave re-labelling of the column to a different component - e.g. the application or reporting tool that consumes this result set.

Answer (score 2):

**I strongly recommend to do this kind of renaming in application layer**.

But if you still insist you can use Dynamic-SQL:

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375411)**

```
DECLARE @A AS VARCHAR(12)= GETDATE()-1;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
  N'SELECT [Data], 
      SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Dt, GETDATE()) = 1 AND Type = ''Stock'' THEN SPEND END) AS <placeholder>
    FROM #vw_ZZ_AS_ComplianceLeagueTable
    GROUP BY [Data];';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<placeholder>', QUOTENAME(@A));

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
       @sql;
```

Another possibility is to use `sp_rename` function:

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375412)**

```
DECLARE @A AS VARCHAR(12)= GETDATE()-1;

SELECT [Data], 
      SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Dt, GETDATE()) = 1 AND Type = 'Stock' THEN SPEND END) AS [placeholder]
INTO #temp
FROM #vw_ZZ_AS_ComplianceLeagueTable
GROUP BY [Data];

 DECLARE @new_name NVARCHAR(128) = QUOTENAME(@A);

EXEC tempdb..sp_rename '#temp.placeholder', @new_name, 'COLUMN'; 

SELECT *
FROM #temp;
```